# Fetch sibling nodes linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an XML as below. I will have to fetch the title when the path is d:\mypath. I tried below one but it is not giving as expected. I would like implement it in LINQ to XML.

My code:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(file);
string mypath = @"D:\\Mypath";
var result = xdoc.Descendants("child")
    .Where(i => (string)i.Element("content").Element("path") == mypath)
    .Select(i => (string)i.Element("title")).FirstOrDefault();
```

For now I have finished my task using `XPathSelectElement` as below, but I am interested to in LINQ query :

```
string a = (string)xdoc.XPathSelectElement(
    "//child/content[path='" + mypath + "']/../doc_attributes/title");
```

Sample XML:

```xml
<parent>
    <doc>
        <order>testorder</order>
        <preorder>yes</preorder>
    </doc>
    <childs>
        <child>
            <doc_attributes>
                <id>090015b3804fb931</id>
                <title>CTA</title>
            </doc_attributes>
            <content>
                <path>D:\\Mypath</path>
            </content>
        </child>
    </childs>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, you're just forgetting to check the [Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value(v=vs.110).aspx) property

```
.Where(i => i.Element("content").Element("path").Value == mypath)
```